# generate xml file pre defined schema in mvc C# from list

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller, schema

creation of xml file using schema in mvc c# procedure

Comment: A schema is XML format so you can use any xml library class to generate the schema.

Comment: It would be good if you provide more detail, code - what errors you are getting and what is the expected output. This isnt much to go on. Just by the minimal context, you can use XmlSerialization to generate your XML and then save it as a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **System.Xml.Linq.XNamespace** to use **Xml Schema**.
Example method is as follows:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public void CreateXmlFile(string name)
    {
        XNamespace xsi = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        XNamespace xsd = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        XNamespace ns  = XNamespace.Get("http://schema.test.com/test");

        new XDocument(
                          new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
                          new XElement(

                              ns + "root",
                              new XAttribute("xmlns", ns.NamespaceName),
                              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", xsd.NamespaceName),
                              new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.NamespaceName),
                              new XElement(ns + "Person",
                                 new XElement(ns + "Name", name)
                              )
                          )
                      )
                      .Save(@"Your XML Path");
    }
```